# v4.master page - access is denied on saving

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've got a plain vanilla SharePoint2010 Blank Site installed (through the wizard) in a Win2k8 VM. When attempting to save changes to the v4.master page, I get an access denied error. I'm logged in as a local admin. I've tried editing the file with VS2010 and with Notepad++. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you in the site collection administrators group and it's still failing? Or, are you saying you're local admin on the physical machine?

Comment: Chris - I'm in the site collection administrators group and local admin on the physical machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Guys... File permission setting in the folder. I did not have Full control permission. Enabling this for me allowed the edits, although, this shouldn't be done anyway. Thanks, Chris for the input.